# Word order of "Something to Someone"

Tags: ordre-des-mots

> La permission ? Pourquoi ne pas **la lui** demander ?
>
> NOT: La permission ? Pourquoi ne pas **lui la** demander ?

In the first example above ("demander Something à Someone"), the correct word order is "la(Something)" followed by "lui(Someone)", not the other way around.

On the other hand, in the following second example ("faire parvenir Something à Someone"), the correct word order is "me(Someone)" followed by "la(Something)".

> La table ? Il vient tout juste de **me la** faire parvenir.
>
> NOT: La table ? Il vient tout juste de **la me** faire parvenir.

What causes the opposite word order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does not depend on the verb but rather on the personal pronoun:

- *Me, te, nous, vous* will appear first
- *Lui, leur* will appear last

> La permission ? Pourquoi ne pas **la lui** demander ? *or* **la leur** demander
>
> La permission ? Pourquoi ne pas **me la** demander ? *or* **nous la** demander

Also

> La table ? Il vient tout juste de **la lui** faire parvenir.

is perfectly right.

Comment: To @SteffX: So should the sentence "Les briques... Ne **me les** fais pas tomber sur la tête." be converted into "Les briques... Ne **les lui** fais pas tomber sur la tête." Merci.